# Way to set XCode project-specific variables?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I have a demo XCode 4 project I plan to make available for download to some customers, however it uses an external library that I need to reference in the source and linker search paths. I would like to use a variable (similar to $(MY_LIB_DIR)). I know I can set this up as an environment variable, but I would rather the users didn't have to go through the hassle. In other dev environments I have used there is a way to set my own project variables, does XCode support this same concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you bundle the external library? If so, you can add $SRCROOT/ext/MyFavoriteExtLib to the search path in the project and it should find it on any machine.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I was hoping to reference an external dir, but it was certainly easier for now to bundle my own copy of the lib and use $SRCROOT. Thanks Brian!